# Google Maps Javascript API not rendering

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on using the Google Maps API. I believe I have followed the tutorial exactly, but for whatever reason, the map is not rendering. I'm not getting any error messages in the console, so I'm not too sure where to look for more error info.

The following is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=[THE KEY]"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

And the JS:

```
var map;
function loadMap(){
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.39404819, -91.38743867),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", loadMap());
```

Finally, the CSS:

```
#map {
height: 75%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It's gotta be something small that I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems with the posted code:

1. `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", loadMap());` executes the `loadMap` function immediately and assigns the return value as the function to be executed on `window` load.  It should be:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", loadMap);
```

2. your map doesn't have a size.  It is 100% of the div with `class="content"` which doesn't have a size.

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS should be:

```
#map {
height: 75%;
}

html, body, .content {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

(or whatever matches your layout and gives a height to the `div` with `class="content")

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zyfzdreL/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function loadMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.39404819, -91.38743867),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", loadMap);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 75%;
}

html,
body,
.content {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```